# How to convert date to an arbitrary format in FME Workbench?

Tags: fme-form

My source dataset is DWG and destination is GDB. The source dataset has Date attributes as Char in DD-MM-YYYY. The corresponding destination attributes have to be of Date datatype, that too in M/D/YYYY format.

I tried DateFormatter transformer, with output date format string as **FME Date (%D)**, I got the error as

`The date 'FME Date (05/14/1981)' is not valid. Valid forms for a date type are YYYYMMDD, YYYYMMDDHHMMSS, or HHMMSS`

For format string as **%D**, I got error as:

`The date '05/14/1981' is not valid. Valid forms for a date type are YYYYMMDD, YYYYMMDDHHMMSS, or HHMMSS`

For format string as **%m"/"%e"/"%Y** and **%m/%e/%Y**, again the above error message.

As from the error, I cannot perform the desired formation. Is there a transformer available in FME Workbench to perform desired format conversion? Or should I try something like using **`SubstringExtractor`** and then **`StringConcatenator`**? I need to read the documentation thoroughly to see if I can get it working.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try `%Y%m%d`, `%Y%m%d%H%M%S` or `%H%M%S`.

**Update:** There seems to be two issues that the `DateFormatter` is unable to deal with:

1. Hyphens, and
2. Days before months in numeric formats, such as 30/12/2011.

To work around both these issues I came up with the following:
[image: FME Workbench screenshot]

The first two transformers just create a dummy test feature with a date attribute of `30-12-2011`.

- The `AttributeSplitter` creates a list out of the date by splitting
  it at the hyphens.
- The `AttributeExposer` makes the list elements
  visible as individual attributes.
- The `StringConcatenator` reorders
  the list elements and adds slashes, resulting in MM/DD/YYYY format.
- The `DateFormatter` then converts back to YYYYMMDD, zero-padding the
  month/day where necessary.

The writer is a file geodatabase writer that writes a single row to a table. It runs and the output viewed in ArcCatalog is as expected: TEST_DATE is displayed as `12/30/2011`.

Comment: @bhah238: Read my question please. I need date to be in M/D/YYYY format only.

Comment: It should work. Try it if you haven't. Dates in geodatabases are stored as YYYYMMDDHHMMSS, though they are formatted according to your date/regional settings when displayed.

Comment: Actually there seems to be two issues that the `DateFormatter` is unable to deal with: 1) Hyphens and 2) days before months in numeric formats. There's probably a few ways to work around this, I'll update my answer if I can figure it out.

Comment: Updated answer, see if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks. Transformation did take place, but I think I messed-up somewhere. I used the input date string in `AttributeCreator` as **21-6-1984**,but got the output in GDB as **21-06-1984**. The problem seems to with `StringConcatenator` since in its output, it shows both Destination Attribute as well as the parts of the date fields as produced by the `AttributeExposer`. And hence the `DateFormatter` shows the same fields as `StringConcatenator`. By the way, what date format string should I use in `DateFormatter`?

Comment: The Creator/AttributeCreator transformers are only there for testing purposes, you wouldn't use them in your actual workspace. I only have them to create a dummy test feature.

Comment: As for the date displaying as 21-06-1984, my guess is it's displayed that way because of your regional/date settings.

Comment: The DateFormatter string should be `%Y%m%d`.

Comment: OK. I am going to convert the workspace into a CustomTransformer and plug it into my actual workspace.

Comment: Agian the same error message `The date '/5/14/1981/' is not valid. Valid forms for a date type are YYYYMMDD, YYYYMMDDHHMMSS, or HHMMSS`. Can I share my workspace with you on StackExchange?

Comment: Let's try this chat thingy out.